# Cannot equalize images

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib, scikit-image

I'm using the library skimage in Python for increasing the contrast of my images.
My images are in RGB in a list called `X_train` whose image shape is: (32x32x3).

First I convert it to `[0, 1]`, then from RGB to HSV and then I use the method from the library:

```
X_train = X_train/256
X_train_hsv = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(X_train)
X_train_eq = skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist(X_train_hsv, kernel_size=None,
                                                 clip_limit=0.01, nbins=256, )
```

The thing is that I obtain this error:

```
/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skimage/exposure/_adapthist.py in interpolate(image, xslice, yslice, mapLU, mapRU, mapLB, mapRB, lut)

        333                  int(xslice[0]):int(xslice[-1] + 1)]
        334     im_slice = lut[view]
    --> 335     new = ((y_inv_coef * (x_inv_coef * mapLU[im_slice]
        336                           + x_coef * mapRU[im_slice])
        337             + y_coef * (x_inv_coef * mapLB[im_slice]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2175,2) (2175,2,32,3)
```

Does anybody know what could be my mistake?

Comment: I run your code but I did not get any error. Could you please post the full tracebak?

Answer (score 2):

According to [scikit-image documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist), you don't need to rescale the images to 0..1 and convert them from RGB to HSV:

> #### Notes
>
> - **For color images, the following steps are performed:**
>
>   - The image is converted to HSV color space
>   - The CLAHE algorithm is run on the V (Value) channel
>   - The image is converted back to RGB space and returned
> - For RGBA images, the original alpha channel is removed.

So, as you are using the default values for keyword arguments `kernel_size`, `clip_limit` and `nbins`, you could simply write:

```
X_train_eq = skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist(X_train)
```